# xps document printed from wpf - too short, strange paper size?

Tags: .net, wpf, printing, report, xps

I'm testing a wpf application printing capabilities by just printing to an xps file.. stragely, even though the paper size settings are correct for the system, it seems to shorten my 8.5x11" paper down to some odd side, almost approaching square instead of rectangular. This is messing up the layout of my report pretty badly. The same report printed to PDF seems to work fine, as well as printed to a physical printer.

Any strange XPS bugs or something I should look out for?

Comment: Have you specified if it's centimeter or inches ?

Comment: i actually defined the size in the native DPI that it uses.. works fine for other printers, just the xps thing messes up.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any Layout Transforms? I've had similar problems when using transforms and would need to clear them out prior to printing and then reset them.

Comment: i think there's a few in there, i'll have to dbl check.